# How to write text with parameter and variable

Tags: java, variables, parameters, while-loop

Have an assignment I cant figure out. The assignment is:

1. With a given method:

   ```
   static void writeTexts(String text, int amount);
   ```

   Print out the text in the parameter text as many times as given by the variable amount. Every print of text on separate line.
2. Print an empty line for every third time text is printed.
3. Write a `main` method with one or more calls of `writeTexts` with appropriate test data (don't know what this means) to check that the method works in all cases.

I'm a beginner and find this very difficult, have been reading and watching tutorials, also searched and found a similar question, but can`t seem to grasp this. Any help is appreciated.

The error I get when running my code is:

```
cannot find symbol.
```

What I got so far:

```
public class Task {

    static void writeTexts(String text, int amount) {
        amount = 0;
        text = "hallo";
        while (amount< 3) {
            System.out.println(text);
            amount++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeTexts(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete error that you get.

Comment: The method `writeTexts` expects two parameters, but in `main` only one parameter is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

- You are overwriting `amount` with `0` and you are overwriting `text` with "hallo" which is incorrect because you will be printing "hallo" instead of `text` and you lose track of how many time you need to print.

  ```
  amount = 0;
  text = "hallo";
  ```
- Your loop will always only iterate 3 times.  Instead you should iterate `amount` times. To do this, you will also need a counter `i`

  ```
  int i = 0;
  while (i < amount) {
  ```
- You are not printing an empty line every third time text is printed.  You should add this:

  ```
  i++;
  if (amount % 3 == 0) { // If amount is divisible by 3
      System.out.println();
  }
  ```

Comment: Ok so I did this:public class Task {

static void writeTexts(String text, int amount) {
  int i = 0;
  while (amount< i) {
  System.out.println(text);
  i++;
  if (amount % 3 == 0) { // If amount is divisible by 3
    System.out.println("");
}
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  writeTexts("hallo", 3);

}
} But its not printing anything

Comment: Please actually double check your work before you ask why it doesn' t work.  All you had to do was copy the code I provided correctly, which you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void writeTexts(String text, int amount) {
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        //Check if the line is the a multiple of 3
        //then print an empty line
        //I use i + 1 because I start at 0 which is a multiple of 3
        //but we are not interested by the that
        if( (i + 1) % 3 == 0 ){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        //Print the text
        System.out.println(text);
}
```

Now for `calls of writeTexts with appropriate test data` that essentially means call the function with so the appropriate parameters e.g: `writeText("Halo 3", 3)`.
I would strongly recommend you to read some more on function to get better grasp of how they work.